# not able to assign or read value from collapsed input field (text box) in responsive datatable

Tags: datatables

Datatable in view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
        <table id="mainDivInvoiceItemTable" class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center"><strong><u>I</u></strong>tem Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Discription</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center"><strong><u>Q</u></strong>uantity</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center"><strong><u>U</u></strong>nit Price</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center"><strong><u>T</u></strong>ax 1</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center"><strong><u>T</u></strong>ax 2</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Total Before Tax</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">&nbsp</th>
                </tr>
                 </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    <%
           if (Model.NewInvoiceItemList != null)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < Model.NewInvoiceItemList.Count; i++)
               {
                   string cls = string.Empty;

                   if (string.Compare(Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ItemDescription, "13335588990101") == 0)
                   {
                       cls = "hide";
                   }                       
                   %>
                    <tr class="InvoiceItemTableRow <%: cls %>"", id="<%:"NewItemRow"+i%>">                           
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                           <%: Html.DropDownList(string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].ItemList", i), Model.GetSelectedItemList(Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].InvoiceItemId, Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ItemName), new { @class = "InvoiceItemRow DDList1", @id = string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__ItemList", i),  @style="width: 125px; text-align:center" })%>
                           <input id="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__ItemName", i) %>" name="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].ItemName", i) %>" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ItemName %>" data-tag="12345" />           

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ItemDescription, new { @class = "InvoiceItemRow1",  @style="width: 150px; text-align:center" })%>
                            <div class="note"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ItemDescription, "", new { @style="color:red;"}) %></div>  
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Quantity, new { @class = "InvoiceItemRow Qty AmountTextBox",  @style="width: 125px; text-align:center" })%>
                            <div class="note"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Quantity, "", new { @style="color:red;"}) %></div>   
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].UnitPrice, new { @class = "InvoiceItemRow Price AmountTextBox",  @style="width: 125px; text-align:center" })%>
                            <div class="note"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].UnitPrice, "", new { @style="color:red;"}) %></div>   
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <%:Html.CustomDropdown(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Id, string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__Tax1Id", i), string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].Tax1Id", i), Model.GetSelectedTaxList(Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Id, Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Name, Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Val.ToString()), "Text", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "InvoiceItemRow DDList2 invoicetax" },  {"style", "width: 125px; text-align:center" } })%>
                             <input id="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__Tax1Name", i) %>" name="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].Tax1Name", i) %>" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Name %>" />
                              <input id="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__Tax1Val", i) %>" name="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].Tax1Val", i) %>" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Val %>" />          
                            <div class="note"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax1Id, "", new { @style="color:red;"}) %></div>   
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <%:Html.CustomDropdown(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Id, string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__Tax2Id", i), string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].Tax2Id", i), Model.GetSelectedTaxList(Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Id, Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Name, Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Val.ToString()), "Text", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "InvoiceItemRow DDList2 invoicetax" },  {"style", "width: 125px; text-align:center" } })%>
                             <input id="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__Tax2Name", i) %>" name="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].Tax2Name", i) %>" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Name %>" />
                            <input id="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList_{0}__Tax2Val", i) %>" name="<%: string.Format("NewInvoiceItemList[{0}].Tax2Val", i) %>" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Val %>" />           
                            <div class="note"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].Tax2Id, "", new { @style="color:red;"}) %></div>   
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">                        
                            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].BeforeTaxAmount, new { @class = "InvoiceItemRow BeforeTaxAmount AmountTextBox", @readonly = "readonly",  @style="width: 125px; text-align:center" })%>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                          <a href="#" id="NewItemDelete<%:i %>" data-invitemid="0" class="DeleteItem" style="width: 10px; text-align:center" >
                                    <img src="/Images/IconDelete2D.png" title="Delete" alt="Delete" style="height: 20px; width: 15px" />
                                    </a>
                           <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].InvoiceItemId)%>
                           <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ExpenseList)%>
                            <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ProjectId)%>
                             <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ProjectName)%>
                              <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ProjectStaffId)%>
                               <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].StaffName)%>
                                <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].ExpenseCategoryId)%>
                                 <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NewInvoiceItemList[i].CategoryName)%>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                    <% }
           }%>
                 </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery code that recalculates and assigns value to BeforeTaxAmount text box when value is changed in Quantity textbox.

$("#mainDivInvoiceItemTable, #mainDivInvoiceServiceTable").on('blur', '.Qty', function () {

```
    var qtytextboxid = $(this).attr("id");
    var qtytextboxvalue = $('#' + qtytextboxid).val();
    var pricetextboxid = qtytextboxid.replace("Quantity", "UnitPrice");
    var pricetextboxvalue = $('#' + pricetextboxid).val();
    var amtbeforetaxtextboxid = qtytextboxid.replace("Quantity", "BeforeTaxAmount");
    var BeforeTaxValue = qtytextboxvalue * pricetextboxvalue;

    $('#' + amtbeforetaxtextboxid).val(BeforeTaxValue.toFixed(2));
    subTotal();
});
```

Everything works fine when datatable is not collapsed. But when it collapses, BeforeTaxAmount text box is no longer on the screen and value does not get assigned to it.

How do I make sure that value gets assigned to BeforeTaxAmount even if it is not on the screen as datatable is collapsed?

Would greatly appreciate help. I have looked and looked and goolged and goolged.....

Thanks,

JrD

Answer (score 0):

```
$('text', editor.field( 'Quantity' ).node()).on( 'change', function () {

var c = editor.field( 'Cost' ).val();
var q = editor.field( 'Quantity' ).val();
var total = (c * q);

editor.val( 'Total', total );
} );
```

This is something that I use that may help. So basically when quantity changes, it updates the total field by multiplying cost and quantity together.